# add specific tooltip to arraytoDataTable

Tags: datatable, tooltip, dataview, limesurvey

I would like to add specific tooltips to my graph. However, I have trouble adding them in the ArraytoDataTable. I have read somewhere that I should add "datatable.setcolumnproperty(3, 'role', 'tooltip')". 
But maybe it is not in a valid place? Or do I have to specify the role earlier?

This is my code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['corechart'] } );

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {


var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Kenmerk', 'Belangrijkheid', 'tooltip', { role: 'style' } ],
    ['testa', {10}, 'tooltip1', 'color: #394165'],
    ['testb', {20}, 'tooltip2', 'color: #0CA5AA'],
    ['testc', {30}, 'tooltip3', 'color: #F2941A'],
    ['testd', {40}, 'tooltip4', 'color: #E64E67']
    datatable.setcolumnproperty(3, 'role', 'tooltip');
  ]);

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc: function(dt, rowIndex) { return dt.getValue (rowIndex, 1).toString() + '%' },
                     sourceColumn: 1,
                     type: "string",
                     role: "annotation" },
                   2]);



  // Set chart options

var options = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    title: 'Hoe belangrijk vindt u elk kenmerk (in percentages uitgedrukt)',
    vAxis:  { format: '#\'%\'', maxValue: '100', minValue: '0'},
    legend: { position: 'none'},
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
          };


  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
 </script>
  <p>
 </p>
 <div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the way you defined the tool tip is wrong. Check this fiddle to see how to do it correctly.

In this line,

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Kenmerk', 'Belangrijkheid', 'tooltip', { role: 'style' } ]
```

Replace tool tip like this,

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Kenmerk', 'Belangrijkheid', {label: 'tooltip', role: 'tooltip'},{ role: 'style' } ],
```

Check this fiddle for more information
http://jsfiddle.net/ovxLjqyn/