# Adding Variation to a Standard Google Bar Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm using a standard bar chart based on Google's code description

```
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
      ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
      ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
      ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
      ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
    ]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
      },
      bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    };
```

The problem is that I have more data, like the variation in Sales in 2014, that I would like to get included in the chart = maybe as whisker lines or an additional number that overlay when you mouseover a bar.  Is this even possible?  If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can do this (it's a bit more complicated with html because you have to find the classic graph options)

[add specific tooltip to arraytoDataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965688/add-specific-tooltip-to-arraytodatatable)